# Landscape 17.03 - timezone setting

Tags: landscape, timezone

we're running 17.03 Landscape on premises server and I have a question regarding timezone setting. Everything is displayed in EDT for some reason.

[image: Computer list]

The machine is configured for EEST:

```
timedatectl 
      Local time: Tue 2018-03-27 11:23:18 EEST
  Universal time: Tue 2018-03-27 08:23:18 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2018-03-27 08:23:18
       Time zone: Europe/Bucharest (EEST, +0300)
 Network time on: yes
 NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Is there a way to configure the Landscape server as the timezone of the machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my own question.

The setting for timezone is related to the user's login profile.
So, what one needs to do is to go to it's profile, edit settings and choose a timezone from the drop-down menu and click save.

[Desired EEST timezone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X0ix.png)