# Change landscape Timezone

Tags: landscape

How do I change the timezone for Ubuntu Landscape? The server time is EDT (set with `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`) but Landscape is showing everything as UTC

```
$ timedatectl
                      Local time: Thu 2019-04-25 11:22:29 EDT
                  Universal time: Thu 2019-04-25 15:22:29 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 2019-04-25 15:22:29
                       Time zone: US/Eastern (EDT, -0400)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Landscape doesn't have a "timezone" setting as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019577/landscape-17-03-timezone-setting). 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't configure timezones on the server itself. To quote the answer from the question you linked:

> The setting for timezone is related to the user's login profile

The screenshot you posted shows various account profiles and settings. Your user profile accessible by clicking your user name in the top right (just beside logout). Timezone and API keys are configured there.

Comment: "clicking your user name in the top right (just beside logout)" is what i was looking for